# Input should take in positive integers for values but I need to account for float to account for possible user error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner to Python. Any help is appreciated!
My program wants the user to enter in positive integer values. How do I take into account user error if someone enters in a float value? I converted input to float instead of int because if the user input in a float value, the program would give an error instead of re-prompting the user for input again which is what I want to happen. I should prompt the user for just int values but want to accept float values so that I can re-ask the user again.

```
while(True):
    a = float(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
    b = float(input("Enter another positive integer: "))

    if type(a) == float and type(b) == float:
        print("Floats don't count. Let's try again.")
        continue 

    if a >= 0 and b >= 0:
        break
    else:
        print("Let's try again.")
        continue
```

Comment: How and where are you capturing input? If it's a string you can validate it before converting with something like `int()`. Consider a regular expression like `/\A\d+\z/` meaning "consists of one or more digits".

Comment: @tadman: Unless they're forbidden to use exceptions, the correct way to check for valid `int` is to convert with `int()` and handle `ValueError`s as appropriate. The complete set of valid integer strings is broader than just "composed of digits" (e.g. leading and trailing whitespace is allowed and ignored, a `-` or `+` prefix is allowed, etc.). `str.isdigit` (and related functions) exist even if you wanted to do string tests, so regex is massive overkill even if exceptions are forbidden.

Comment: You're assigning `a = float(input(...))`, so `type(a) == float` is **guaranteed** to be true!

Comment: I prompt the user in the beginning of the while loop. So I should convert the input to int and handle ValueErrors? How would I handle ValueError?

Comment: I don't understand the whole float business.  If they enter `1.5`, do you want to handle that differently than if they enter a nonsense answer like `hamburger`?  Or would you want to simply re-prompt in both cases?

Comment: As other comments have hinted note that using `float()` rather than `int()` doesn't really help. Try `float("argle")`. In other words, if the user doesn't enter a valid number you will still get an exception that you have to handle.